# How to update row with unique column

Tags: java, hibernate

I have database schema with unique column `CONSTRAINT CLASSA_FIELD UNIQUE (FIELD)`. I need to update rows in this table, but when I call update/flush I receive `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DBSCHEMA.IDX_CLASSA_FIELD) violated.`. 
I've tried to add `updatable = false` annotation, `merge(entity)` but neither of them works. Any tip how to update such row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when you have a unique constraint on a database field it means that the value in the field has to be unique against all other values in that field across all rows of the table. So to help answer this I'd suggest you let us know what value you're trying to update the field to. Also "rows" suggests you're trying to update more than one row, possibly w/ the same value. If this is true than that's your problem there.

Comment: Nevermind, after your comment I realised that I set every needed field, except ID field, so actually my update method worked as save, and since I've tried to save object with the same value, which was marked as unique, I got exceptions.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Mind +1 my comment? Somehow it got set to 0... despite helping solve the issue.